# Python Loop Behavior with Generators

Tags: python, loops, return, generator, yield

I am confused about why different looping constructs behave so differently when used with a simple generator. Consider the following code:

```
example_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for_count = 0
next_count = 0
while_count = 0

def consumer(iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        yield    
    return

for item in consumer(example_list):
    print("For Count: {0}".format(for_count))
    for_count += 1

# First while loop
while consumer(example_list).next():
    print("Next Count: {0}".format(next_count))
    next_count += 1

# Second while loop
while consumer(example_list):
    print("While Count: {0}".format(while_count))
    while_count += 1
    if while_count > 10: # add contrived limit for infinite loop
        break
```

The output for this code is:

> For Count: 0
>   For Count: 1
>   For Count: 2
>   For Count: 3
>   For Count: 4
>   While Count: 0
>   While Count: 1
>   While Count: 2
>   While Count: 3
>   While Count: 4
>   While Count: 5
>   While Count: 6
>   While Count: 7
>   While Count: 8
>   While Count: 9
>   While Count: 10

I would appreciate help understanding the following:

1. How does the `for` loop know when to end but not the second `while` loop? I expected both `while` loops to exit immediately since `None` is yielded.
2. Why doesn't using `.next()` raise an exception? The `consumer` routine isn't a class with a `__next__()` method defined, so does it magically appear when you use the `yield` keyword?
3. Why is it that if I change `consumer` to `yield item`, the first `while` loop become infinite like the second one?
4. If I change `consumer` to simply return instead of yielding anything, the second `while` loop exits immediate instead of becoming infinite. I've been under the impression that a `yield` is essentially a `return` that you can resume from. Why are they treated differently by a `while` loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The `for` loop

Your first for loop works as expected.
**Update**: [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) noted that your `yield` is not accompanied by the expected `item`, so it just returns `[None, None, None, None, None]` rather than `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` - but it still iterates over the list.

### The first `while` loop

[The very same commentator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) also noticed that the first while loop never starts because `0` is a `False`-equivalent in Python.

### The second `while` loop

In the second while loop, you are testing the value of `consumer(example_list)`. This is the generator object itself, not the values return by its `next()`. The object itself never equals None, or any other `False` equivalent - so your loop never ends.

This can be seen by printing the value of `consumer(example_list)`, your while condition, within the loop:

```
>>> while_count=0
>>> while consumer(example_list):
...     print while_count, consumer(example_list)
...     while_count += 1
...     if while_count > 10:
...         break
```

Giving:

```
0 <generator object consumer at 0x1044a1b90>
1 <generator object consumer at 0x1044a1b90>
2 <generator object consumer at 0x1044a1b90>
3 <generator object consumer at 0x1044a1b90>
4 <generator object consumer at 0x1044a1b90>
5 <generator object consumer at 0x1044a1b90>
6 <generator object consumer at 0x1044a1b90>
7 <generator object consumer at 0x1044a1b90>
8 <generator object consumer at 0x1044a1b90>
9 <generator object consumer at 0x1044a1b90>
10 <generator object consumer at 0x1044a1b90>
```

The second item is the object, which never equals `None`.

Comment: And the middle example returns `0` the first time, which *does* evaluate as `False` thus terminating that loop immediately.

Comment: @MarkRansom True, good point. Didn't event look at that loop.

Comment: Actually I was mistaken, since there's nothing after the `yield` it returns `None` not `0`, which also evaluates as `False`. So I was right but for the wrong reason.

Comment: @MarkRansom - Splendid. BTW, working with breakpoints and a debugger would have made it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Answering only a subset of your question:

Your misconception with the `while` loops is, that a `while` loop does not iterate over a generator object by itself, as a `for item in generator`  loop does.

The `consumer(example_list)` in your second while loop always returns a generator, which evaluates as a boolean True, hence the loops runs forever.

In the first while loop, you're testing the first yield value from that generator, which is `None`. Hence, the loop doesn't even start.